# A field or property with the name <variable> was not found on the selected data source

Tags: c#, sql

It's my first time to implement INNER JOIN query in SQL.NET and C#.NET. I get this error:

> A field or property with the name 'Prep_By' was not found on the selected data source.

I don't understand what is the problem, the field 'Prep_By' is existing in my database.

Here's what I got:

```
private void LoadFeedback()
{
    con = new SqlConnection(Connectiontxt);
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd;
    if (seardata == "")
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT  [Articles_Tbl].[Article_ID], [Articles_Tbl].[Title], [Articles_Tbl].[Mod_Date], [Users_Tbl].[Name] FROM [Articles_Tbl]  INNER JOIN [Users_Tbl] ON [Users_Tbl].[User_ID] = [Articles_Tbl].[Prep_By] where  [Articles_Tbl].[Status] = 'Approved' and (Article_ID = '')", con);

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "ss");
        gridrfqheader0.DataSource = ds.Tables["ss"];
        gridrfqheader0.DataBind();
    }
    else {
        cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT  [Articles_Tbl].[Article_ID], [Articles_Tbl].[Title], [Articles_Tbl].[Mod_Date], [Users_Tbl].[Name] FROM [Articles_Tbl]  INNER JOIN [Users_Tbl] ON [Users_Tbl].[User_ID] = [Articles_Tbl].[Prep_By]  where  [Articles_Tbl].[Status] = 'Approved' and (Article_ID LIKE '%" + seardata + "%' or Title LIKE '%" + seardata + "%')", con);

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "ss");
        gridrfqheader0.DataSource = ds.Tables["ss"];
        gridrfqheader0.DataBind();
    }

}
```

Comment: it might be in your database, but you are not selecting it.

Comment: Post the Schema for the tables

Comment: You have a serious SQL injection vulnerability that needs to be addressed immediately.

Comment: @asawyer Can you give me some tips?

Comment: @SomaSchicksal You want to at a minimum parameterize your input into inline SQL statements. Here is a good example: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Parametrized_SQL_statement#C.23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that gridrfqheader0 contains a binding reference to Prep_By, but you are not including it in your SELECT statement.

Try adding it:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Articles_Tbl].[Prep_By], [Articles_Tbl].[Article_ID])...
```

As a side note, your conditional statements contain a lot of duplicate code. Consider moving the code that gets data into one location so that you do't have duplicate code. For example:

```
if (isNullOrEmpty(seardata)) 
{   
cmd = new SqlCommand(your query); 
} 
else 
{  
 cmd = new SqlCommand(your other query); 
}

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds, "ss");
gridrfqheader0.DataSource = ds.Tables["ss"];
gridrfqheader0.DataBind();
```

It can be further refactored, but this is a good start.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Dataset to bind Grid, and in Grid you are using [Prep_By] field which not in your dataset.
So Simply just

Add `"[Articles_Tbl].[Prep_By]"` in your select statenment.

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Articles_Tbl].[Prep_By],  [Articles_Tbl].[Article_ID], [Articles_Tbl].[Title], [Articles_Tbl].[Mod_Date], [Users_Tbl].[Name] FROM [Articles_Tbl]  INNER JOIN [Users_Tbl] ON [Users_Tbl].[User_ID] = [Articles_Tbl].[Prep_By] where  [Articles_Tbl].[Status] = 'Approved' and (Article_ID = '')", con);
```

make change in both sql queries..

Answer (score 0):

If the grid has the column created with the source name Prep_By you have to select that column from the database.